# Parameters(XSRF Token) are not passed in the response cookie when using proxy

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using a flask application hosted by Nginx that sends the XSRF token to the client as a cookie.

In my Angular 8 app I'm using proxy.conf.json:

```
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://XXX.domain.net",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,

  }
}
```

Im browsing from: http://localhost:4200/ and when I open the cookies page I see the domain is "https://XXX.domain.net" not localhost so I can't use the cookie. 
My question is how do I config the cookie to work on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your `proxy.conf.js` file is correct. 
Try it as an array:

```
const proxyConfig = [
    {
        context: ['/api'],
        target: 'https://my-website-where-my-backend-is.com/',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
    }];
```

Comment: It is a json file not js file